# When can I use "have a good day"?

Tags: time, valediction

I just want to ask if when would be the exact time to use have a good day? Because someone told me that the appropriate time would be in morning. Is that correct?

Comment: I would use it from 8 a.m. to 2 p.m. Any earlier than 8 a.m. and you risk pissing off cranky early-risers; any later than 2 p.m. is needless because the work-day is practically over, and usually people only use this phrase concerning work-days.

Comment: The *exact time*? Anytime. You can use any English words anytime you want (unless there are local legal prohibitions such as yelling "*Fire!*" in a crowded theater). As for "*appropriate time*" to say something - that's primarily opinion-based. E L & U is not an etiquette site.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree with most of what WS2 says, they have not answered your specific question, which is about whether *Have a good day* is limited to the morning. And the answer is No, it is not. If you use it, you can use it any time of the day, though probably not when it is getting dark.

And *contra* WS2, who has assumed you are using the phrase with a stranger as a conventional farewell, there are contexts where I suspect even WS2 would use it with no qualms: when waving friends or family off for a day out somewhere.

Comment: Enjoy your day out! Don't get eaten by the lions (for people going to the zoo)! Hope the sun shines. Say hello to Blackpool! Bring us a stick of rock! Happy travels! Don't push the stones over (for anyone going to Stonehenge)!                                                 ' Have a nice day' is symptomatic of the dumbed-down, brain-in-perpetual-neutral, society in which we live. People need to learn to use their God-given imaginations. Specifically, the art of closing conversations should be taught in Primary School!

Comment: Our local supermarket employed a retired civil-engineer, who had also been in the army, as a  check-out cashier. He always had a few entertaining remarks to make. Older people, like I, used to queue at his cash desk because one was always guaranteed a lively conversation and a laugh. And he operated, I feel certain, just as fast as the others. Sadly he is no longer there, no doubt a victim of the social trend I have described. Not nearly enough emphasis is placed by the education system on the art of conversation.

Comment: But the question wasn't about _Have a nice day_!

Comment: No it was about 'Have a good day', which I adjudge is fast becoming the new 'Have a nice day'.

Comment: So you answer a specific question about what part of a day a phrase may be used with a personal rant about a _different_ phrase. Great.

Answer (score 1):

Since time of day differs, depending on who and where you are talking to. Being mindful of the time is important when talking long distance. Have a good day is a positive and hopeful sentence and can be used during the day until sundown. After that you could say did you have a good day? This then Opens up lines of communication about what happened during day.
This is just my humble opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, never! The expression is so hackneyed and overdone as to make many want to scream. Even worse than this, is people who say at about 9.00pm  'Enjoy the rest of your evening'! What I suspect you are looking for is a way of closing conversations. This is an art, and needs cultivation. A range of options are available to start you off, depending on who you are addressing: e.g. 'Keep well!', 'stay safe'!, 'Look after yourself', 'Be good', 'It was nice to meet you, bye', 'Hope all goes well' etc. But most importantly, vary your closing remarks. And use your imagination to think up others!

Comment: Is it okay to use have a good day on afternoon?

Comment: I agree that a little variety is nice, and may help improve a greeting or farewell, but I think that "never" is overstating this one a bit, and there's a bit of hyperbole going on to say that "many" would want to "scream" simply because someone is offering a polite greeting in the hallway or in the checkout line. (If not, well, have a nice aneurism.)

Comment: I saw a bumper sticker in New York which said 'Don't f***ing-well tell me to have a nice day', or words to that effect. Any hyperbole is not originating from me. 'Have a nice day' is symptomatic of the de-personalised orthodoxy which eats away at pleasant social life.